# It happened again: My question has been closed inadvertently

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

So it happened again. [One of my questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1514471/why-does-the-supermicro-mainboard-x10dri-not-fit-in-the-supermicro-case-745tq-r9) has been closed inadvertently. The folks who have closed it claimed that it is not about hardware as outlined in the help center.

However:

1) I have read [the relevant part of the help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). There is absolutely no doubt that my question *is* about hardware as outlined there, unless the community here since my last visit has agreed that mainboards and computer cases are not considered hardware any more.

2) There are dozens of questions which are nearly literally like mine, or very similar. A few examples:

[Can this motherboard fit into this case?](https://superuser.com/questions/1485265/can-this-motherboard-fit-into-this-case?rq=1) (literally the same, online since more than three months, no votes to close)

[Will a pedestal motherboard fit into a(ny) regular case?](https://superuser.com/questions/559610/will-a-pedestal-motherboard-fit-into-any-regular-case?rq=1) (online since six years, no votes to close)

[How do I know if this Motherboard will fit in the case?](https://superuser.com/questions/733562/how-do-i-know-if-this-motherboard-will-fit-in-the-case?rq=1) (also online since six years, no votes to close)

So why the heck has my question been closed?

This now is the second time within a few weeks that this happened.

The first time the mod who closed it showed a very mature behavior by reopening it although I had a little dispute with him due to the close where *I* was behaving immature and possibly insulted him (at least, I chose inappropriate wording).

I think I'll leave here forever and give others the same advice if the situation is not resolved. There are only a few things which are more frustrating than (being a non-native speaker) carefully crafting a question which clearly adheres to all site policies, doing your own extensive research before, checking the question for orthographic and errors and correct wording, and then having it inadvertently closed.

So I hope somebody with enough power reopens that question or explains in detail in which way it is off-topic. Only claiming that it is off-topic because it is not about hardware is not a sufficient explanation, because it obviously *is* about hardware.

Comment: The only people who can answer your question are employees of SuperMicro. You should ask their support **why** your board is not listed as compatible with your chassis. It is not a question we can answer for you.

Comment: I voted to reopen since you did an edit. I would like to know the answer also.

Answer (score 2):

> So it happened again. One of my questions has been closed inadvertently. The folks who have closed it claimed that it is not about hardware as outlined in the help center.

There isn’t anything inadvertently about the close vote I issued.   The question was originally asking a question that only the manufacturer in question can answer.

> There are dozens of questions which are nearly literally like mine, or very similar.

Those examples only asked if the hardware was compatible or incompatible.  You were asking if the documentation, which is the documentation anyone in this community would use to answer that question about your hardware, was actually correct or incorrect.  You also wanted to know the reason the documentation was correct or incorrect.

> So why the heck has my question been closed?

The only reason I had was due to the fact you asked the reason the documentation was correct or incorrect.  Questions asking the reason a manufacturer has made something incompatible or compatible is impossible to answer.  While your edit clarified what you were looking for, you never removed that part of the question, which might have resulted to in the question being reopened.

> The first time the mod who closed it showed a very mature behavior by reopening it although I had a little dispute with him due to the close where I was behaving immature and possibly insulted him (at least, I chose inappropriate wording).

This only is evidence of our excellent moderator team treating everyone the same.

> I think I'll leave here forever and give others the same advice if the situation is not resolved. There are only a few things which are more frustrating than (being a non-native speaker) carefully crafting a question which clearly adheres to all site policies, doing your own extensive research before, checking the question for orthographic and errors and correct wording, and then having it inadvertently closed.

I am not sure you understand what inadvertently actually means.  I purposely issued a closed vote due to what you were asking.  You wanted to know something I thought only the manufacturer could actually answer.  *Using my best judgment I avoided a discussion about my vote by not leaving a comment purposely.*

However, my single vote to close your question, is exactly that a single vote.  Only moderators have binding votes.

> So I hope somebody with enough power reopens that question or explains in detail in which way it is off-topic. Only claiming that it is off-topic because it is not about hardware is not a sufficient explanation, because it obviously is about hardware.

Since you question the accuracy of the documentation, there isn’t any way the community can answer your question, which is the reason you should contact the manufacturer.

> Perhaps other will read the comments and learn from the discussion (as I do), so: Questions asking the reason a manufacturer has made something incompatible or compatible is impossible to answer. It seems were are getting closer to the problem now. There is a severe misunderstanding. Of course, I am absolutely not interested in why Supermicro decided to make them incompatible. My why was meant in the technical sense. I was hoping for an answer like, for example, "because the screw holes in the mainboard do not match the standoff holes in that case".

If the documentation is incorrect, as you suspect, the only way to know if they are compatible is to have the hardware.  The documentation is supposed to indicate what motherboard form factors the case supports.   So I looked at the documentation.

The case supports 13.68" x 13" EE-ATX SuperMicro motherboards.  The SuperMicro X10DRi is 12" x 13" E-ATX, this determination was entirely based on the definition of what EE-ATX (only used by SuperMicro) and the particular E-ATX variation used by SuperMicro/ASUS.  However, it’s clear the supported motherboards is not a complete list. There are both EE-ATX and E-ATX motherboards in that list.  In the question’s current form it could be reasonably be answered, there are motherboards using the same E-ATX specification as the motherboard your asking about.

I have issued a vote to reopen your question.

Comment: I will not be reading any commentary to this answer.  You seem to have wanted an explanation on the reason your question was closed.  I have tried to explain calmly in clear language my reason for my own vote to close the question.  I also hinted at the reason I personally won’t vote to reopen the question in its current form.

Comment: Perhaps other will read the comments and learn from the discussion (as I do), so: *Questions asking the reason a manufacturer has made something incompatible or compatible is impossible to answer.* It seems were are getting closer to the problem now. There is a severe misunderstanding. Of course, I am absolutely not interested in why Supermicro ***decided*** to make them incompatible. My **why** was meant in the technical sense. I was hoping for an answer like, for example, "because the screw holes in the mainboard do not match the standoff holes in that case". I'll clarify my question again.